# AttributeError: 'Pinecone' object has no attribute 'from_texts'

Tags: vector-database, pinecone

I am trying to create embeddings for the chunk text which I have created, but when I try to use the method from_texts, i am getting the following error

```
AttributeError: 'Pinecone' object has no attribute 'from_texts'
```

This is my code.

```
model_name = "sentence-transformers/all-mpnet-base-v2"
model_kwargs = {'device': 'cpu'}
encode_kwargs = {'normalize_embeddings': False}
hf = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
    model_name=model_name,
    model_kwargs=model_kwargs,
    encode_kwargs=encode_kwargs
)

pc = Pinecone(api_key=pinecone_api_key)
pc.Index=pinecone_index
pc.from_texts([t.page_content for t in text_chunks],hf,pinecone_index)
```

Is this method got depreceated? what is the alternate method for this

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

Seems that you are using a not suitable Pinecone object.

## Solution

If you are looking for a .from_text method, import Pinecone from `langchain`

```py
from langchain.vectorstores import Pinecone as PC

docs_chunks = [t.page_content for t in text_chunks]
pinecone_index = PC.from_texts(
    docs_chunks,
    hf,
    index_name='your-index-name'
)
```

## Extra Ball

Similar problem in the Pinecone community site: https://community.pinecone.io/t/pinecone-from-texts-not-working/4149/3

Answer (score 0):

use this methode i tried and its worked for me

```
from pinecone import Pinecone
pc = Pinecone(api_key="your api_key")  

 
index_name="your index name"
index = pc.Index(index_name)  
for i, t in zip(range(len(text_chunks)), text_chunks):
   query_result = embeddings.embed_query(t.page_content)
   index.upsert(
   vectors=[
        {
            "id": str(i),  # Convert i to a string
            "values": query_result, 
            "metadata": {"text":str(text_chunks[i].page_content)} # meta data as dic
        }
    ],
    namespace="real" 
)

    index.describe_index_stats()
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**